# Using DBContext with Exasol

Tags: c#, .net, exasol

I have a requirement to connect to Exasol from .Net app and use DBContext for data retrieval / manipulation.

From what I understand Exasol is not natively supported by Entita Framework and there is no official provider.

Any experience using 3rd party providers / any other way to get Exasol in DBContext running?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/connect_exasol/drivers/ado_net.htm